# Can I use react to create a subdomain application?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which is live example.com. I want to create a simple holiday rental booking system application like Airbnb but not as advanced. I would like to create this using react, my question is can I create a react application on a subdomain e.g booking.example.com and would there be any problems in doing it that way? From what I have read, I would need to create a custom post type and then make axios requests to pull the data from the database and also the same for post requests.

Alternatively could I potentially create the react application and embed it on a single page template? I want people to be able to create an account, post their own rental properties and pay in order to list it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install React,npm on your server.
If you are using Apache or Cpanel, then you can create .htaccess file on your react app subdomain root directory.

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
DirectoryIndex
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:PORT/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

Make are you will change the PORT according to your requirements.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have started building the application embedded into my current site using the ReactPress plugin. Are you familiar with it, if so which method would be better in terms of scalability and potentially separating the application from the WordPress site? It is a custom-built WordPress site.

Comment: No, I don't know about this plugin.
But the provided htaccess code will be working fine for react app on the apache server.